# What is the default image quality of JPEG using Android camera?

Tags: android, image, jpeg

I already known that I can choose the image quality(compression quality? not sure) of JPEG from 0 to 100.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(saveFile, true);
saveBitmap.compress (android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
```

but I don't know *what is the default image quality(compression quality? not sure) of JPEG*? Is that 100?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no image quality. There is only compression quality. What do you mean?

Comment: I mean if the image quality 0,the compress rate(compression quality) is 100%(100).If the image quality 100,the compress rate(compression quality) is 0%(0). Which one is default quality? Is 0 or 100?

Comment: Dont understand a word of this. You better rephrase your post as it is unclear what you want to know.

Comment: Could you tell me the default compression quality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Quality" is not part of JPEG. The quality after JPEG compression is determined by the quantization tables selected and sampling used. Some encoders use a "quality" setting to simplify that. However, there is no guarentee that one encoder's quality "X" is equivalent to another encoder's quality "X".

Comment: I got it.Thanks for your answer.